# Understading why looping subplot does not work with loc()

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, seaborn

Considering the following toy dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=["A"])` 
my_ID = ["control", "sample1", "sample2", "sample3"] 
new_ID = 25 * my_ID
df["new_ID"] = new_ID
```

I make a subplot for `df["A"]` based on the unique values of `df["new_ID"]` as follows:

```
unique_list = list(df["new_ID"].unique())
fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(len(unique_list) / 2) , 2)  
for unique_sample, ax in zip(unique_list, axs.flat):  
   sns.histplot(data=df[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample], x= "A", ax=ax)
   ax.set_title(unique_sample)
```

The code functions well as we use `df[df["new_ID"]]`.
However, the script will give us four same subplots if we write it as:

```
d = df.loc[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample] 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(len(unique_list) / 2) , 2)   
for unique_sample, ax in zip(unique_list, axs.flat):  
    g1 = sns.histplot(data=d, x= "A", ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(unique_sample)
```

I am wondering why loc() cannot be used in iteration, although, we can use it in making single plots.

Comment: What's the definition of `d`? We're missing information and without it, can only guess. You say `loc` can't be used. What happens if you use it?

Comment: `d` had been omitted because of wrong formatting. Edited! If use `loc`, all the subplots will be the same and it seems the loop does not go through the full `unique_list`. Nevertheless, when I print the unpacked `unique_sample` and `ax`,  the outcome shows the iteration is happening

Comment: `sns.displot(data=df, x='A', col='new_ID', col_wrap=2, common_norm=False)` is all you need.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks for the response! I have no problem making the graph using the first script I have written. The actual question is why for `data` in `sns.displot()`, we cannot use `data = df.loc[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample]` instead of `df[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample]`.

Comment: I just realized when I write the `d = df.loc[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample]` before `for loop`, the graphs are not generated correctly. but moving the line after `for loop` solves the issue. But why `d` cannot be accessed in every loop, when we define it before the loop? because I think when the iteration happens, in `data = d`, the `d` is still accessible. Or it is not what it happens?

Comment: So basically, selecting data was done outside the loop, where unique_sample didn’t change.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks! so, if I have the data before the loop, is there a way to still make the loop work properly. I mean for example if before loop I write `i = 0` and `df.loc[df["new_ID"] == unique_list[i]]`, and at the end of the loop I write `i += 1`, or  something like?

Comment: No, `d = df.loc[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample]` needs to be inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce unfortunately. Using your code - there are four different plots. seaborn 0.11.2, pandas 1.3.5.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=["A"])
my_ID = ["control", "sample1", "sample2", "sample3"] 
new_ID = 25 * my_ID
df["new_ID"] = new_ID 

unique_list = df["new_ID"].unique()
print(unique_list)

#I make a subplot for df["A"] based on the unique values of df["new_ID"] as follows:

fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(len(unique_list) / 2) , 2)  
for unique_sample, ax in zip(unique_list, axs.flat):  
   sns.histplot(data=df[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample], x= "A", ax=ax)
   ax.set_title(unique_sample) 
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

For what it's worth, consider using `sns.displot(kind="hist", ...)` for this job! It has built in support for facet grid and will do the "facetting" by new_ID easily for you, you don't have to manage the axes manually.

This is all it takes to get the equivalent display:

```
sns.displot(data=df, col="new_ID", col_wrap=2, x="A");
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. My main question has been why we cannot use `data = df.loc[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample]` instead of  `df[df["new_ID"] == unique_sample]`. In other words, why using `loc` method for calling the data we only get similar graphs?

Comment: We can use loc, it works the exact same way here, we just have to call it in the same place (inside the loop).